# Rails 3.2.13 LoadError during deployment on Glassfish Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, warbler

I use a war file generated by warbler(1.3.8) to deploy a basic RoR application (only one model generated by scaffold and only the standard gems) to a Glassfish server (3.1.2.2). After starting the server i get a load error like this:

org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) Exception loading extension `KryptcoreService`: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream handler unavailable due to: null

I have tried everthing: different jruby versions, different rails versions and Java upgrades to 1.7.040 both on development and production environment.

Any ideas what I could do else?

Answer (score 1):

Could get it working using in gemfile

gem "jruby-openssl", "~> 0.8.8"

Answer (score 0):

With jruby 1.7.x the ssl gem is included in the jruby jars. To add a seperate ssl gem should not work. I solved the topic by adding a WEB-INF/init.rb file with the content
$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared'
require 'jopenssl'

see https://github.com/jruby/warbler/issues/266#issuecomment-71327274